# Two classes of discretionary protection

Tags: databases

I am reading security chapter of book titled `Introduction to database system`.

It said that discretionary protection can be divided into two subclasses c1 and c2.

Class c1 distinguishes between ownership and access.

class c2 additionally requires accountability support through sign-on procedures, auditing, and resource isolation. 
Does sign on procedures mean autentication such as checking user name and password?
I wonder how class c1 distinguishes between ownership and access without sign on procedures?

Answer (score 1):

C1 and C2 are just terms from the [Orange Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Computer_System_Evaluation_Criteria) for levels of protection (where C2 has more security than C1). You can read the actual definitions online in [the TCSE](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/history/dod85.pdf) itself:

Here it is:

> Class (C1): Discretionary Security Protection
>
> The Trusted Computing Base (TCB) of a class (C1) system nominally
>   satisfies the discretionary security requirements by providing separation of
>   users and data. It incorporates some form of credible controls capable of
>   enforcing access limitations on an individual basis, i.e., ostensibly suitable
>   for allowing users to be able to protect project or private information
>   and to keep other users from accidentally reading or destroying their data.
>   The class (C1) environment is expected to be one of cooperating users
>   processing data at the same level(s) of sensitivity.
>
> Class (C2): Controlled Access Protection
>
> Systems in this class enforce a more finely grained discretionary
>   access control than (C1) systems, making users individually accountable for
>   their actions through login procedures, auditing of security-relevant
>   events, and resource isolation.

So C2 is a superset of C1, which does additional logging and finer grained access control (for example, there would not be a group login - logins would be individual).

Also, these terms (C1 and C2) are broader than just database security; they really refer to the security of an entire computing environment.

Comment: It may be because of my weakness in English, I don't understand the sentences `class c1 distinguishes between ownership and access `  and `class c1 provides separation of user and data.`
Two sentences are saying the same thing.But i do not understand both.